# Setting page title from @ Page directive in ASP.NET using master pages

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, master-pages

I am using master pages and am having trouble setting page titles from the @ Page directive.  All of my classes inherit from a class *myPage* which inherits from the ASP.NET *System.Web.UI.Page* class. **Please Note:** I have **runat="server"** set in my master page's head tag.

Here's what my @ Page directives look like for the file **test.aspx.vb**:

```
<%@ Page language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MainMaster.master" 
autoeventwireup="false" CodeFile="test.aspx.vb" 
Inherits="test" Title="test" %>
```

Here's what **test.aspx.vb** looks like:

```
Partial Class test
    Inherits myPage

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

End Class
```

This is what my master file, **MainMaster.master**, looks like:

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="MainMaster.master.vb" Inherits="MainMaster" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
    <title>untitled</title>
</head>
...
```

Now, when you go to view **test.aspx** in a browser you'd expect to see the title 'test'. but instead you will see 'untitled' as per the master page.  Through trial and error, I modified the *test* class to inherit from *System.Web.UI.Page* directly, instead of *myPage* like this:

```
Partial Class test
    Inherits Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

End Class
```

and everything worked just fine. Why would my pages being children of *myPage* instead of *System.Web.UI.Page* prevent the title from being set correctly in the @ Page directive?

I realize that I could just set the page titles programmatically through the *Page_Load* methods in every page, but I'd rather do it in the @ Page directives in the .aspx files.

This is a very weird and frustrating problem, and I'm at a loss!

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thank everyone for their help; I have found a solution. The problem was that the *myPage* class had a property for Title, but in the Set part of the property was not passing the changes on to *Page.Title* as it should have been.

A one line change fixed my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

What methods do you have in your base page (myPage.vb).

If you are overriding any of the default methods, are you calling the base versions of those pages?

in C# I'd have something like this:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    // Do my custom processing.

    // Don't forget to call base OnInit here:
    base.OnInit(e);
}
```

If you don't call these methods, then the events that happen in them for you (like wiring up the masterpage's title) won't fire.

Comment: Good suggestion. I actually checked this, and the myPage class does not override any of the Page class's methods--it only adds functionality.  Hilariously, I created an empty child of Page and had the test class inherit from that, and everything worked fine.  There must be a problem with myPage...

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar set up to you.  I have content pages inheriting from a custom base page which is itself inheriting from page.  I am not having any issues with the title being set on the aspx and being shown in the browser.  The only difference I see between my code and yours is my master page has the autoeventwireup property where your master page does not, and also your master page has a property called codefile and mine has codebehind.

**Content Page:**

```
<%@ Page Title="Login to Application X" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/masterpages/mymasterpage.Master"
    CodeBehind="login.aspx.vb" Inherits=".login" %>
```

**Master Page:**

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="mymasterpage.master.vb"
    Inherits=".mymasterpage" %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Dan.  I tried adding AutoEventWireup="false" to my master page with no results. Regarding codebehind vs codefile, apparently codefile has to do with as change made in .NET 2.0: http://www.ddj.com/windows/187202007

Comment: I am using VB.  Specifically i am using .net 2.0 framework within vs 2008 ide.